# C#: Defining fields as private but modifiable within generics

Tags: c#, generics, interface, encapsulation

Is there a way to define a field as `private` but still modifiable within a method using the generic of the containing class?

(Apologies for the length of the question; I am struggling to nail down exactly what I am asking)

Specifically, I currently have three classes `A`, `B`, `C` with the following requirements:

1. `B` and `C` have a field called `name`, but `A` does not
2. `A` and `C` have a method `Load()`, but `B` does not
3. Collections of `B` and `C` use `name` in a custom `Add()` method, but `A` does not use this method

This is my current solution:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public SomeType Load() { ... }
}

public interface IClass {
    string Name {get; set;}
}

public class MyList : SomeCollection<IClass>
{
    // Depends on x.Name, and may modify Name before adding x to the collection
    public new void Add(IClass x) { ... }
}

public class A : BaseClass { ... }

public class B : IClass { ... }

public class C : BaseClass, IClass { ... }
```

This solution works for me if `Name` has a public `set`. But is there some way to properly encapsulate `x.Name` so that `Add` can modify `x.Name`, but `x.Name` cannot be modified in instances of `B` and `C`?

Comment: I think you may have over-abstracted your problem. I've no idea what relevance `A`, `BaseClass` and `Load` have in relation to the rest of the problem. I've no idea what "`Add` can modify it, but other instances of `IClass` classes cannot" even means.

Comment: `A` doesn't have a `Name` property, so I can't subclass it from something with `Name` in it, which `MyList` requires. But `A` and `C` do need to share the other method. (BTW: You are probably right; am I making this too hard?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is *no*. You cannot selectively expose members to specific classes, and `MyList` has no inheritance relationship with `IClass`.
What you can do, however, is create an additional *internal* interface (or possibly make `IClass` internal) that exposes the `Name` property and implement it *explicitly*. This means that in order to read/write the `Name` property, you would need to cast an instance to the internal interface, which would be possible only within the assembly it is defined.

```
internal interface IClassName { string Name { get; set; } }

public class MyList : Collection<IClass>
{
    protected override void InsertItem(int index, IClass item)
    {
        var className = item as IClassName;
        if (className != null)
        {
            // do something with className.Name ...
        }
        base.InsertItem(index, item);
    }
}

public class B : IClassName { string IClassName.Name { get; set; } }
```

Note I'm not using the **new** keyword to bypass the base class' `Add` method since this would override the polymorphism (e.g. if you'd cast an instance of `MyList` to `IList<IClass>` the original implementation of `Add` would be called - and that's bad.) Instead I'm overriding the appropriate method from the `Collection<T>` class, which is designed for collection inheritance.

Comment: I think this is very close, but I am struggling to implement it. If `B` is `IClassName` (rather than `IClass`), then I can't use `InsertItem` on it. Is it something like a wrapper to a separate `public class B : IClass`?

Comment: Thanks, B can now be used in `InsertItem`, but now `b.Name` must be public (where `b` is an instance of `B`). Is there a way to prohibit `b.Name = "new name"`?

Comment: I worked out a way to do it which doesn't require changing `b.Name`, which I probably should have done from the beginning. But I very much appreciate your help. Have some points.